# C++ Lambda segmentation fault

Tags: c++, reference, lambda, function-pointers, capture

The following code produces a segmentation fault and I don't know why:

```
    myTree<int> tree;
    tree.insert(10); // not important

    std::vector<int> v = tree.toVector(); // Segmentation fault
```

This is the myTree code (reduced, not compilable, just enough to understand what it's about):

```
template<class T> struct node {
    T key;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    int count;

    node(const T &k=T(), node *l=0, node *r=0) {
        key = k;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        count = 1;
    }
};

template<class T> class myTree {
public:
    myTree() {
        root = 0;
    }

    void traverseInOrder(void (*visitFunc)(node<T>* n)) {
        traverseInOrder(visitFunc, root);
    }

    std::vector<T> toVector() {
        std::vector<T> v;
        traverseInOrder([&](node<T>* n) {
            v.insert(v.end(), n->count, n->key);
        });
        return v;
    }
private:
    void traverseInOrder(void (*visitFunc)(node<T> *n), node<T> *n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            if (n->left != 0) {
                traverseInOrder(visitFunc, n->left);
            }

            (*visitFunc)(n);

            traverseInOrder(visitFunc, n->right);
        }
    }

    node<T> *root;
};
```

The segmentation fault occurs in this line:

```
v.insert(v.end(), n->count, n->key);
```

The NetBeans variables window says v is OUT_OF_SCOPE.

**Question: Am I using the lambda correctly?**

Note: I am using g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 (Cygwin).

Comment: Is this a question about how to understand the code you wrote and how to use a debugger?

Comment: What's the value of t? Also, try step into insert() call and find out what's the value of `this`in there. Compare to `&v` in the stack frame above where `v` is defined.

Comment: Ah - this is interesting. According to this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2993349/3458) only stateless lambdas can be passed as function pointers. Yours is not stateless.

Comment: Good point by @Arkadiy - Which compiler is this?

Comment: Please paste some fully compilable and running example... We're missing insertRoot, and traverseInOrder definition does not match your call. Out of this, the lambda syntax seems right

Comment: @not-sehe It really wasn't important, it's just another variant of insert. I updated the code.

Comment: @robert Perhaps you should try to make the veracity of that claim a little more apparent.

Comment: @not-sehe Perhaps you should stop not contributing.

Comment: WUT! @robert I have set this code up in my compiler and scrutinized it long time ago. Sorry for contributing in the wrong way. Good day. I won't bother you (PS. LOL you edited s/insertRoot/insert/ - note that `myTree<>::insert` is also not given...)

Comment: @not-sehe It was never my intention to provide reduced code that is compilable. Sorry for that (I'll add a note). But you were not really nice, either ("stupidly omitted").

Comment: @robert the above code shouldn't compile, let alone run.  Does your compiler actually compile the above?  And if so, what is the version and name of it, so I can avoid it?

Comment: @Yakk It's g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 (Cygwin). Yes, it compiles (of course, the above code is only a reduced extract).

Comment: [Wow, Gcc 4.7.2 is broken](http://ideone.com/EshjSv) -- an actual reduced version that shows the broken behavior.  It appears to happen when you have a lambda in a member of a `template` `class` which is converted to a function pointer.  The code that makes sure it is stateless doesn't run, and we get complete nonsense.

Comment: @robert Fair enough. The thing is, whenever we see someone trying to implement his own container (list, or tree) we can statistically safely assume there's UB in the pointer handling. It's excruciatingly naive to omit that part. Of course, we now know you weren't _that naive_ and I owe you an apology for my bad judgement. Herewith, sorry for my snappy response. (and +1)

Comment: @not-sehe No problem, I'm sorry, too. Next time I'll write a question with properly reduced code and there will be no need for snappyness (on either side). :-)

Comment: @Yakk I am kind of relieved that this is a compiler bug. I almost went nuts...

Comment: @Robert as an aside, the linked ideone is a good reduced example.  It compliles, runs, and segfaults.  I generated it by eliminating everything from your code that did not stop the segfault.  When asking a question here, doing that step first is considered polite.

Comment: Oh, and your cide us still wrong.  The compiler should hav rejected it ehen compiling rather than segfaulting when running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by @Arkadiy in the comments, a stateful lambda does not decay to a function pointer. The fix is to write your `traverseInOrder` as a template that takes a callable object

```
template<class Func>
void traverseInOrder(Func visitFunc)) {
    traverseInOrder(visitFunc, root);
}
```

Alternatively, you could be more type-safe and give it a signature that takes a `std::function` that returns `void`  and takes a `node<T>*`

```
void traverseInOrder(std::function<void(node<T>*)> visitFunc)) {
    traverseInOrder(visitFunc, root);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Sorry for not providing a compilable example.

Comment: @robert - could you record the compiler and its version as part of the question? That really should be a compile-time error.

Comment: @robert glad to have been of help!

Comment: @Arkadiy I am using g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 (Cygwin). I'll add a note to the question.